# Android toolbar not updating until tapping on overflow menu icon

Tags: android, toolbar

I had `MainActivity` which extends `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and toolbar with search, filter icons and other options in overflow menu, when i load a certain fragment i want search icon to disappear and show filter icon. As in my code below i'm trying to hide search icon and show filter icon but the tool bar gets updated only when i tap on the overflow menu icon. I'm confused where I'm going wrong...any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

`MY_FRAGMENT.Java`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Log.v("oncreate", "");
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.v("onPrepareOptionsMenu", "");
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).setVisible(true).setEnabled(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification).setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);
    activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications).setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
activity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

to

```
activity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: should we calling this?? `activity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Boss, activity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); actually is not necessary to call, as per docs invalidateOptionsMenu() would generally do the trick,but for some reason Its not working for me...Please check the updated code.